# What is an appropriate name for the partition $\{\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\}$ of the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$?

Tags: terminology, set-partition

This notation has come up in a paper I'm co-working on.  We're currently calling $$\{\{1\},\{2\},\ldots,\{n\}\}$$ the *partition of singletons*.  This name seems suitable.  However, I'm not sure what to call $$\{\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\},$$ and I'm guessing there's a name for it in the literature that I'm unaware of.

**Question**: What is an appropriate name for the partition $\{\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\}$ of the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$?

Comment: Perhaps the undivided partition?  The total partition?  The complete partition?  The unseparated partition?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an official name,
but I would call it a monoset.